# Provide a minimum amount and a maximum amount of parameters to a provided argparse argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, argparse

Lets say I have the following class:

```
import argparse

class Parser(argparse.ArgumentParser):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Parser, self).__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def optparse():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument(
            "-g", "--geo", default=None, dest="geoLocation",
            help="Accepts two to four parameters"
        )
        return parser.parse_args()
```

And I need to have the geo argument accept a minimum of two parameters (`-g 1 2`) and a maximum of four parameters (`-g 1 2 3 4`) and everything in between (`-g 1 2 3`). How can I do this using argparse, while keeping the code compatible with python 2.7-3.x?

Comment: `nargs='+'` is the closest you get in `argparse`.  Check the exact numbers after parsing.

Comment: @hpaulj I thought that would probably work best, thank you